# Custom image slider issue (image bumped to new line)

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, slide

I'm having trouble with sliding an image into view using JQuery. Basically, the slide into view works fine (using .animate) but the image that should be pushed out of view (from left to right) is actually just being bumped down. Here's my code:

```
var new_id = $(img).attr("id") - 1;
var src_tag = document.getElementById(new_id);
var src = "img/large/" + $(src_tag).attr("src").replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
var img_tag = "<img src=\"" +  src  + "\" id=\"" + new_id + "\" 
                style=\"display:inline; position: relative; left:-944px; \" />";

$('#insert-image').prepend(img_tag);
$(img[0]).animate({left: '+=944px'}, 'fast');
```

and my html:

```
<div id="insert-image-wrapper">
    <div id="insert-image" class="main-content">
        <img src="img/large/colour-version.png" id="4" style="display:inline;">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
div.main-content{
    width: 944px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#insert-image-wrapper{
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
}

#insert-image{
    width:944px;
    height:518px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:none;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$(img[0]).animate({left: '+=9440px'}, 'fast');`

Isn't this 9440px is too wide for your page?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it should be +=944px. Thanks! This just happened when I was copying my code over and changing a couple of things.

Comment: So..should i post this as answer ? ;)

Comment: haha, yeah, unfortunately it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

this is not tested but maybe can helpful:
change css to :

```
#insert-image-wrapper{
    width:945px; 
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
div.main-content{
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.main-content img{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width: 944px;
}
#insert-image{
    width:2000px;
    height:518px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still has the same problem of bumping the image onto a new line and then finishing it's slide in.